# Unreachable code following a video exactly

Tags: java

So i'm coding this for a class, watching the professor and copying exactly as he does however my code returns with an unreachable code error and his does not.
His code https://gyazo.com/2f7cdf5f27cdba414af5105fa6c33121
and my code below

```
private long getGcdBreak(long m, long n)
{
    long result;
    while(true);
    {
        result = n % m;
        if( result == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        n = m;
        m = result;
    }

    return m;
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: `while(true);` remove semi-colon in while clause it should be `while(true) `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the semicolon (which terminates your `while` with an empty statement).

```
while(true) // ;
{
```

Comment: Jesus coding gives me a headache. I've been sitting here for a solid half-hour trying to figure out what I screwed up and you saw it in 10 seconds. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Kenny Welcome to the world of professional coding

Comment: Haha, thankfully this is only an intro class.